# Running gradle -version does not return proper information

Tags: gradle

I will start of by saying I have set up gradle on multiple machines before without issue.

On one particular machine, I have set up gradle, but when I run "gradle - version", I get the following output:

[image]

No matter what gradle command I run, it always outputs the same information as above. For examples if I run "gradle tasks" it will still return what you see above. "gradle -version" should be something similar to this:

---

### Gradle 2.6

Build time:   2015-08-10 13:15:06 UTC

Build number: none

Revision:     233bbf8e47c82f72cb898b3e0a96b85d0aad166e

Groovy:       2.3.10

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

JVM:          1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)

OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Any information on how to get this corrected is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are you running it from the correct directory>

Answer (score 2):

A couple possibilities:

- Does `gradle --version` behave differently?
- Is there a `build.gradle` file in that folder? This is the default message when Gradle cannot find a build file.
- Do you have any content in a `gradle.properties` file in that folder? Invalid properties may cause `gradle` to always return the output of `:help`.

I hope one of those is helpful, at least.

Comment: I do not have any build.gradle files in that folder. I have also tried running within different directories and the same issue occurs. Also, gradle --version does the same thin. And I also do not have any gradle.properties file either.

Comment: Hmmm.. how did you install Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The output you posted above is the output of `gradle :help` and not the output of `gradle -version`.

If you omit the `:help` from your command it should print the correct output. (The :help is on the second line of your command line, see red marker on your screenshot)

Comment: The  :help is put in after running the gradle - version command. I did not type in :help, it just appears after running the gradle -version command.

Comment: Do you have some default tasks defined in your configuration? Try to find out where that :help comes from

Comment: There are no default tasks configured. I have also tried deleting my gradle folder and replacing it but that also has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Have you checked all places where gradle can be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `GRADLE_HOME` value you set in your environment variables?
If that is pointing to your previous version, you need to change that.

I am on a mac and for me, I had this value in my .bash_profile

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.4.1
```

I changed it to

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/latest
```

Now `gradle --version` returns latest version as 4.0.1 which I installed a few mins ago. I believe, I won't have to change it any more now!